# Unexpected layers were generated in the mnist example in Tensorboard

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorboard

In order to learn tensorflow, I executed this tensorflow official mnist script ([cnn_mnist.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/layers/cnn_mnist.py)) and displayed the graph with tensorboard.

The following is part of the code.
This network contains two conv layers and two dense layers.

```
conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=input_layer,filters=32,kernel_size=[5, 5],
      padding="same",activation=tf.nn.relu)

pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv1, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)

conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=pool1,filters=64,kernel_size=[5, 5],
      padding="same",activation=tf.nn.relu)

pool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv2, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)

pool2_flat = tf.reshape(pool2, [-1, 7 * 7 * 64])

dense = tf.layers.dense(inputs=pool2_flat, units=1024, activation=tf.nn.relu)

dropout = tf.layers.dropout(
      inputs=dense, rate=0.4, training=mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN)

logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout, units=10)
```

However, looking at the graph generated by tensorboard, there are three conv layers and three dense layers.
I did not expect that `conv2d_1` and `dense_1` will be generated.

Why was `conv2d_1` and `dense_1` generated ?

[image: mnist graph picture generated by tensorboard]

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question, because it sheds some light into inner structure of `tf.layers` wrappers. Let's run two experiments:

- Run the model exactly as in the question.
- Add explicit names to the layers via `name` argument and run again.

### The graph without layers' names

That's the same graph as your, but I expanded and zoomed in to the logits dense layers. Note that `dense_1` contains the layer variables (kernel and bias) and `dense_2` contains the ops (matrix multiplication and addition).

This means that this is **still one layer**, but with **two naming scopes** - `dense_1` and `dense_2`. This happens because this is the second dense layer, and the first one already used the naming scope `dense`. Variables creation is separated from the actual layer logic - there's `build` and `call` method, - and they both try to get a unique name for the scope. This leads to `dense_1` and `dense_2` holding variables and ops respectively.

[image: graph-1]

### The graph with names specified

Now let's add `name='logits'` to the same layer and run again:

```
logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout, units=10, name='logits')
```

[image: graph-2]

You can see there're still 2 variables and 2 ops, but the layer managed to grab one unique name for the scope (`logits`) and put everything inside.

### Conclusion

This is a good example why explicit naming in tensorflow is beneficial, no matter if it's about tensors directly or higher-level layer. There is much less confusion, when the model uses meaningful names, instead of automatically generated ones.

Answer (score 0):

They are just the variables creations and other hidden operations that happen in `tf.layers.conv2d` other than just the convolution operation itself (`tf.nn.conv2d`) and the activation (same goes for the dense layer). There are only 2 convolutions happening: as you can see, if you follow your data in the graph, it never goes through `conv2D_1` or `dense_1`, it's just that the result of these ops (basically the variables needed for the convolution) are also given as input to the convolution operation itself. I'm actually more surprised to not see the same thing appearing for conv_2d though, but I really wouldn't worry for that !